# Vector Math - Determine coordinations of bounding box

Tags: math, vector

[image]

There are two points on the 2D plane, <10, 10> pointing to <30, 50>. How does one determine the coordinates of  if the blue line touches the bounding box of a 100x100 grid using Vector Math?

If you can provide a generalized solution (aka. formula) that would be awesome.

Comment: To me this is a pure math question.

Comment: Well, I am trying to do it in JavaScript. I just need some general idea of how to solve the problem so I can convert it to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two vectors: `a = (10;10)` and `b = (30;50)`. To construct your line, we have `a` as origin and `b` as directional vector, so `g(t) = a + (b-a)*t = (10;10) + (20;40)*t`, where `t` is a parameter of the line. In your example, you are going to check the y coordinate of `g` to be 100: `g(t)[2] = 10 + 40*t = 100 ➪ 40*t = 90 ➪ t = 9/4`. Now put in your `t` in the equitation of `g`: `g(9/4) = (10;10) + (20;40)*(9/4) = (55;100)`. As a result, `(55;100)` is the point that touches the bottom of the bounding box.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, it's my first time to explain math in english rather than german.